# USB boot problem in HP Pavilion G6 (32-bit)

Tags: xubuntu, live-usb, iso, 32-bit, bleachbit

I have a HP pavilion g6 series (32-bit) system. I was using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and everything was working fine until I downloaded BleachBit and used the app incorrectly. It somehow damaged my Ubuntu badly.

I downloaded an ISO image of 32-bit Xubuntu. I have a 64GB sandisk USB, I copied the ISO image to the USB drive but I have another file on the USB device. I tried to boot my laptop with this USB but nothing appears; my system keeps on starting normally.

I want to install this new iso image but I can't. Is there a way to install it without USB or CD?

Comment: Did you follow [the official instructions](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (scroll down to “Easy ways to switch to Ubuntu”)? They're the same for Xubuntu just with a different image file.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to install without usb/cd unless you use pxe boot, or a more advanced install.

Copying the iso to the usb drive will delete everything on it. It must be imaged, not copied. Use 'dd if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/sd?' where sd? is the dev path of your usb drive. Wait a while, it will output nothing. Once it returns, the usb will be imaged and you will be able to boot it.